# Xcode / ItunesConnect: Is it possible to remove watch kit target and add it back or not submit the watchkit App?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, app-store-connect, watchkit

I have a watchkit target in my project. The problem I am facing is I don't need the watchkit target to be uploaded right now. I still want to keep the code however and don't want to delete all the files. Is there a way I can submit the App without the watch kit extension App? I thought about deleting the targets (not the files), but I don't know what is the best course of action in this situation. Can I tell itunesconnect not to include the watchkit App?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you go to the target of your main app and remove the watchkit extension from "Embedded Binaries" it should remove your watchkit app.

Answer (score 2):

To expand upon the answer from Tiago, remove the Watchkit Extension from "Embedded Binaries" and "Target Dependencies."

See [Prevent deploying (disable) WatchKit App with iOS iPhone App in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30426501/prevent-deploying-disable-watchkit-app-with-ios-iphone-app-in-xcode?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.